# Bluetooth does not work but WiFi does on Intel 7265 with both Ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10

Tags: drivers, 16.04, bluetooth, intel, 16.10

On an Acer V3-574-7481 with built-in stock Intel 7265 wireless hardware, WiFi works perfectly but Bluetooth does not. The System Settings applet reports "No Bluetooth adapters found" and the option to enable Bluetooth is grayed out. However, Bluetooth hardware is reported by "dmesg" and a firmware patch file is applied automatically during boot.

**Bluetooth works on this same machine booted into Windows 10.** The machine is dual-boot from separate partitions.

```
# uname -a
Linux galois-l 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# head -6 /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.10 (Yakkety Yak)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.10"
VERSION_ID="16.10"

# rfkill list
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

# lspci -knn | grep -A3 Net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b526 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# hcitool dev
Devices:

# dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   26.310459] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   26.310476] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.310478] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.310480] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.310483] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   26.514833] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[   26.794565] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   26.987853] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   39.604402] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   39.604404] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   39.604407] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

# locate ibt-hw
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.2.27.d.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-22.50.19.14.f.bseq
/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.bseq

# dpkg -S /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq

# dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
Version: 1.161
```

This behavior was identical first under Ubuntu 16.04 and then under 16.10 after upgrade. Command and response examples above are under 16.10 after upgrade.